# Tivoli storage manager installation. The system does not meet the recommended memory requirement

Tags: windows-server-2012, tivoli, tsm

I have Windows server 2012 and I want to install Tivoli storage management server.
My first attempt to install it gave me an error that:

> "The system does not meet the recommended memory requirement of 12
>   GB."

So I have added more memory and now I have 13 GB RAM on my machine.
But now, it tells me that:

> "The system does not meet the recommended memory requirement of 16
>   GB."

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=663&context=SSGSG7&q1=ServerRequirements&uid=swg21064234&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) you see the following memory requirements:

> The following minimum values for memory:
>
> **12 GB**.
>   **16 GB** if you are using data deduplication.
>   **At least 32 GB**
>   for heavily used servers. Using 32 GB or more of memory enhances
>   performance of the Tivoli Storage Manager server database inventory.
>
> If you plan to run multiple instances, each instance requires the
>   memory listed for one server. Multiply the memory for one server by
>   the number of instances planned for the system.
>
> Node replication processing requires additional memory. Use a minimum
>   of 32 GB of memory for node replication without data deduplication.
>   Node replication with data deduplication requires a minimum of 64 GB
>   of memory.
>
> When you create the active log, you need at least 64 GB of memory to
>   run replication. If replication and deduplication are both being used,
>   create an active log of 128 GB in size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following arguments to skip prerequisite check, but it is not reccomended on production systems.
-g -vmargs "-DBYPASS_TSM_REQ_CHECKS=true"